# How can I call a function all the time in a Google Spreadsheet cell?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is my problem:

I created this function on Google Script:

```
function LASTCOLELEMENT(colIndex) {
  // Gets the whole SpreadSheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var registerSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Registro de Inventario");
  // Returns the last element of the colIndex column
  return registerSheet.getRange(registerSheet.getLastRow(), colIndex).getValue()
}
```

And I called it in my spreadsheet as:

```
=LASTCOLELEMENT(1)
```

The output is correct and it gives me what I want, but as soon as I add a row to "Registro de inventario" sheet, "=LASTCOLELEMENT(1)" still shows what was being showing before because it hasn't been called again.

If I delete "=LASTCOLELEMENT(1)" and re-write it again it shows the last element.

I've been thinking about it for a while and I don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google sheet caches the result, and thus does not recall your function and does not refresh the data, because the formula parameter `(1)` does not change, so google inferes that the result does not change neither; eventhough the data that is being used does change, but that is beyond the google sheet inspection.

You might either get used (or educate your users) to make a manual refresh (with Ctrl-R)

Or force a data reload with a trick. Add an unused parameter to the function `function lastColVal(colindex,fakecell)` and pass a reference to a cell `=LASTCOLVAL(1,$A$1)`. Eventhough your function does not use this value, its mere presence will make google sheet to refresh the data.  Then, to force the refresh every time you add a row, change the value of the A1 cell, for example, with a COUNT of nonblank cells.